# Counting the number of appearance of Tuples in a Vector

Tags: vector, julia, find-occurrences

Let vec = [("A", "B"), ("A", "C"), ("A", "D"), ("B", "C"), ("B", "D")] be a vector.
I want to count the number of appearance of each element at each step in the  for loop.

```
function count_occurrences(vec)
    vect = []
    nb_appear_A = 0
    nb_appear_B = 0
    nb_appear_C = 0
    nb_appear_D = 0

    for v in vec
        v1, v2 = v 
        if v1 == "A"
            nb_appear_A += 1
        end
        if v2 == "A"
            nb_appear_A += 1
        end
        if v2 == "B"
            nb_appear_B += 1
        end
        if v1 == "B"
            nb_appear_B += 1
        end
        if v1 == "C"
            nb_appear_C += 1
        end
        if v2 == "C"
            nb_appear_C += 1
        end
        if v1 == "D"
            nb_appear_D += 1
        end
        if v2 == "D"
            nb_appear_D += 1
        end

        # I check for each pairs and push them onto vect
        if v1 == "A" && v2 == "B"
            push!(vect, (nb_appear_A, nb_appear_B))
        elseif v1 == "A" && v2 == "C"
            push!(vect, (nb_appear_A, nb_appear_C))
        elseif v1 == "A" && v2 == "D"
            push!(vect, (nb_appear_A, nb_appear_D))
        elseif v1 == "B" && v2 == "C"
            push!(vect, (nb_appear_B, nb_appear_C))
        elseif v1 == "B" && v2 == "D"
            push!(vect, (nb_appear_B, nb_appear_D))
        elseif v1 == "C" && v2 == "D"
            push!(vect, (nb_appear_C, nb_appear_D))
        end
    end

    return vect
end
 count_occurrences(vec)
5-element Vector{Any}:
 (1, 1)
 (2, 1)
 (3, 1)
 (2, 2)
 (3, 2)
```

This code works, but I would like to apply it for a different vector, say `vec = [("A", "B"), ("A", "C"), ("A", "D"), ("B", "C"), ("R", "E"),...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORRECTION:
After looking at the question code again, I've noticed the results are a bit different. To get values similar to `count_occurences` in the question:

```
function count_occurrences(v)
    d = countmap(Iterators.flatten(v))
    reverse(map(reverse(v)) do p
        r = getindex.(Ref(d), p)
        d[p[1]]-=1
        d[p[2]]-=1
        r
    end)
end
```

But maybe a nicer implementation would be:

```
count_occurrences(v) = foldl(v; 
  init=(Tuple{Int,Int}[],Dict{String,Int}())) do (r,d),(x,y)
    d[x] = get(d,x,0)+1
    d[y] = get(d,y,0)+1
    push!(r, (d[x],d[y]))
    (r,d)
  end |> first
```

ADDITION: An even shorter version of the `foldl` method is:

```
count_occurrences(v) = accumulate(v; 
  init=((0,0),Dict{String,Int}())) do (r,d),(x,y)
    (((d[x] = get(d,x,0)+1;), (d[y] = get(d,y,0)+1;)),d)
  end .|> first
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/counting-the-number-of-appearance-of-tuples-in-a-vector/108901)

```
function count_occurrences(vec)
    vect = []
    nb_appear = Dict()
    for v in vec
        v1, v2 = v
        nb_appear[v1] = get(nb_appear, v1, 0) + 1
        nb_appear[v2] = get(nb_appear, v2, 0) + 1
        push!(vect, (nb_appear[v1], nb_appear[v2]))
    end
    return vect
end
```

Comment: Where is this question from?